# Compatibility with latest Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this code off the internet some years back. But whenever I update my wordpress to the latest Jquery version using Jquery updater plugin, it breaks. As soon as I revert back to the old version, it works again. By breaks, I mean that instead of scrolling to the top of the page, it moves the page up by about 10 pixels.

Is there anything in this code which is now incompatible with latest version of Jquery?

The script is for a button to scroll the page back to the top.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $(window).scroll(function() {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() < 500) {
         $('#scrolltotop') .fadeOut();
      } 
      else {
         $('#scrolltotop') .fadeIn();
      }
   });
   $('#scrolltotop').on('click', function() {
      $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
      return false;
   });
});
</script>
```

Thank you so much for your help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below, hope it'll help

```
   $('#scrolltotop').on('click', function() {
      $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("body").offset().top
            }, 500);
      return false;
   });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help WebMarie, but unfortunately that code doesn't work. The scroll to top image doesn't even appear. Just to make sure I used it correctly, I copied your code and overwrote what was already there between the script tags. If I am using it incorrectly, I apologize in advance.

Comment: Btw, the HTML code for the scrolltotop element is  <a href="#top" id="scrolltotop" title="Scroll to top" style="display: none;"></a>